# How to get Binance websocket real time stream data for multiple coins and assign it to a list?

Tags: python, websocket, binance

My goal is to get real-time price data for 200 coins. I have some codes found somewhere on the internet so not really familiar with all parts. I am quite new to WebSocket:

```
from threading import Thread
from binance.streams import ThreadedWebsocketManager
import time

listOfPairings=["ETHUSDT","BTCUSDT"]
class Stream():
    def start(self):
        self.bm = ThreadedWebsocketManager()
        self.bm.start()
        self.stream_error = False
        self.multiplex_list = list()

        # listOfPairings: all pairs with USDT (over 250 items in list)
        for pairing in listOfPairings:
            self.multiplex_list.append(pairing.lower() + '@trade')
        self.multiplex = self.bm.start_multiplex_socket(callback=self.realtime,streams=self.multiplex_list)

        # monitoring the error
        stop_trades = Thread(target=stream.restart_stream, daemon=True)
        stop_trades.start()

    def realtime(self, msg):
        if 'data' in msg:
            print(msg)
        else:
            self.stream_error = True

    def restart_stream(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            if self.stream_error == True:
                self.bm.stop_socket(self.multiplex)
                time.sleep(5)
                self.stream_error = False
                self.multiplex = self.bm.start_multiplex_socket(callback=self.realtime, streams=self.multiplex_list)
stream = Stream()
stream.start()
stream.bm.join()
```

The output was a bit messy and not in a proper order.

```
{'stream': 'ethusdt@trade', 'data': {'e': 'trade', 'E': 1640252871281, 's': 'ETHUSDT', 't': 714565175, 'p': '3921.77000000', 'q': '0.29930000', 'b': 7166801512, 'a': 7166801524, 'T': 1640252871280, 'm': True, 'M': True}}
{'stream': 'ethusdt@trade', 'data': {'e': 'trade', 'E': 1640252871290, 's': 'ETHUSDT', 't': 714565176, 'p': '3921.75000000', 'q': '0.80950000', 'b': 7166791049, 'a': 7166801536, 'T': 1640252871289, 'm': True, 'M': True}}
{'stream': 'ethusdt@trade', 'data': {'e': 'trade', 'E': 1640252871293, 's': 'ETHUSDT', 't': 714565177, 'p': '3921.75000000', 'q': '1.19660000', 'b': 7166791049, 'a': 7166801545, 'T': 1640252871292, 'm': True, 'M': True}}
{'stream': 'ethusdt@trade', 'data': {'e': 'trade', 'E': 1640252871297, 's': 'ETHUSDT', 't': 714565178, 'p': '3921.75000000', 'q': '0.99390000', 'b': 7166791049, 'a': 7166801556, 'T': 1640252871297, 'm': True, 'M': True}}
{'stream': 'ethusdt@trade', 'data': {'e': 'trade', 'E': 1640252871297, 's': 'ETHUSDT', 't': 714565179, 'p': '3921.43000000', 'q': '0.02550000', 'b': 7166790265, 'a': 7166801557, 'T': 1640252871297, 'm': True, 'M': True}}
{'stream': 'ethusdt@trade', 'data': {'e': 'trade', 'E': 1640252871297, 's': 'ETHUSDT', 't': 714565180, 'p': '3921.36000000', 'q': '0.17450000', 'b': 7166799789, 'a': 7166801557, 'T': 1640252871297, 'm': True, 'M': True}}
{'stream': 'ethusdt@trade', 'data': {'e': 'trade', 'E': 1640252871323, 's': 'ETHUSDT', 't': 714565181, 'p': '3921.32000000', 'q': '0.22830000', 'b': 7166801601, 'a': 7166801598, 'T': 1640252871322, 'm': False, 'M': True}}
{'stream': 'btcusdt@trade', 'data': {'e': 'trade', 'E': 1640252871546, 's': 'BTCUSDT', 't': 1198789220, 'p': '48286.00000000', 'q': '0.00073000', 'b': 8719680198, 'a': 8719681495, 'T': 1640252871545, 'm': True, 'M': True}}
{'stream': 'ethusdt@trade', 'data': {'e': 'trade', 'E': 1640252871789, 's': 'ETHUSDT', 't': 714565182, 'p': '3921.32000000', 'q': '0.17100000', 'b': 7166801737, 'a': 7166801631, 'T': 1640252871789, 'm': False, 'M': True}}
{'stream': 'btcusdt@trade', 'data': {'e': 'trade', 'E': 1640252872393, 's': 'BTCUSDT', 't': 1198789221, 'p': '48286.01000000', 'q': '0.00028000', 'b': 8719681526, 'a': 8719681389, 'T': 1640252872392, 'm': False, 'M': True}}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. For every coin pair, I actually only need one line output for every minute so I can get the price data easily but the reality is that each pair data shows randomly and can print many times. If I want to get the data for 150 coins, they will all be mixed together randomly.
2. How can I assign the stream output to a list? As the stream print every second, it is a bit different to a normal assignment?